# How to assign multiple images to each post in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type called 'portfolio'.

In each of the posts i need to assign X number of images, for use as a slide show on the front end.

I guess a plugin is the best way to go to save some work, but all "slider" plugins i have tried is too much of a complete solution and most often use shortcodes for insertion to the post.

I'd like to just get an array of images in the front end that i can loop trough, since it will most probably be outside the area of the_content() anyway.

Or if you can create your "slides" in a separate tab and then assign it to the post by dropdown or something.

Also, if there can be HTML-content in the slides, thats a plus ;)

TL, DR: Looking for a flexible back-end "slideshow" manager for WordPress that does not rely on shortcodes and gives me the full power on the frontend to write my own html, css & js.

Answer (score 0):

Found this one that did the trick :)

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/